# How to run functions/classes from main?

Tags: c++, function, class, program-entry-point

I know this is a noobie question but how would I do this?...

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>


int main()
{
    TypeText();
}

int TypeText()
{
    printf("Text");
}
```

Comment: Forward declare TypeText() above main.

Comment: TypeText() should have a declaration before main(). There is no reason to have TypeText() return an int either.

Comment: I remember this being in page 1 of any C tutorial worth anything...

Comment: @CTZStef: It doesn't have to be *defined* before `main`.  It only has to be *declared*.

Answer (score 3):

When your compiler sees the call to `TypeText`, it doesn't yet know that `TypeText` exists and what its signature is. You need to declare the function above `main`:

```
void TypeText();

int main()
{
    TypeText();
}

void TypeText()
{
    printf("Text");
}
```

Alternatively, you can just move the definition above `main`:

```
void TypeText()
{
    printf("Text");
}

int main()
{
    TypeText();
}
```

Note that `TypeText` doesn't return anything, so should have return type `void`. You might say the same for `main`, but `main` will actually `return 0;` if you don't explicitly give a return statement.

Comment: Aha thanks I've been trying to work out why id wasn't working, I don't want to start a flame war but I just came from Java which didn't do this :)

Answer (score 0):

You could re-order the functions and define `main` last (after definition of `TypeText()`  function...).

Or you could declare the `TypeText()` function by inserting

```
int TypeText(void);
```

before your `main` (or inside your own header file).

BTW, a `return` statement is missing inside `TypeText` body (or you should declare it as returning `void`)

Don't forget to enable all warnings and debugging info when compiling your file. With GCC that means to compile with `g++ -Wall -g`. And use your debugger (`gdb` ...) when appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it needs predeclaration to help the C++ compiler. You can google the topic, and it looks like someone made an example [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uQZ-Pv-DN6g). This particular type of declaration is known as a [function prototype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prototype).

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>


int TypeText(); //this method is now predeclared to be recognized in main()

int main()
{
    TypeText();
}

int TypeText()
{
    printf("Text");
}
```

Comment: Not "predeclared" -- just declared.

Answer (score 0):

Include the following code at the top of your program:

```
void TypeText();
```

The compiler reads downwards and does not know what your talking about. If you include the code above the compiler, when it sees that function called will search for what its supposed to do.